# Microsoft Account activation incomplete (invalid email)

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-account

I created MS Account by entering an incorrect email address. Then I assigned to that account (prior to activation) promotional product Office 2013 (upgrade from 2010) using the site office.com/offer. At this point, I can not take advantage of the software without activation of the account. Accounts can not be activated without email verification.

Is there any solution to this problem? I don't want to lose of Office 2013, that is assigned to my new MS Account.
Where to possibly get help from MS on this?

Comment: https://account.live.com/ChangeId.aspx may bee change mail account settings.

Comment: Changing default email through this site is forbidden.

Comment: Call Microsoft support.